# C - Reading File Error.. !f_in is null and dont know why?

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault

```
// Trying to read file


void readFilee(char *namefile){

    FILE *f_in = fopen(namefile,"r");
    char x;
    int i = 0;

    if(!f_in){ printf("Error"); exit(0); }

    /* read to EOF */
    while(1){
        x = getc(f_in);
        if(x == '\n') continue;
            archivo[i] = x;
        if(x == EOF) break;
            i++;
    }
    tamArchivo = i;
    fclose(f_in);
}
```

Fact that the error was f_in is null, but I do not understand why? I'm trying to connect a server with multiple clients, the clients are initialized waiting connection.

The command verificion "if" I get "Error"

Comment: Can you post definition of `archivo`? Note that `getc()` returns an `int` and not a `char`.

Comment: You could also check that the call to fopen succeeded (f_in should be non-null)

Comment: Are you using Linux? If so, run it with `gdb ./yourprog` then digit `where` and show us the result

Comment: Try `perror("fopen");` instead of `printf("Error");`. That should tell you why the `fopen` failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

```
archivo[i] = '\0';
```

after the while loop terminate. This will add null charachter at the end of your string `archivo`

also may be the memory space  of your `archivo` array is not sufficient to get the whole content of the file and so it could cause a buffer overflow so it could cause a crash

Answer (score 0):

Verify `f_in` is not NULL before using it. I bet fopen fails and this causes f_in to be NULL. Later when you call `getc`, it will crash.

If that is not the case, try debugging your application with cgdb for instance and see which line causes the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `while (1)` with `while (!feof(f_in))`. This will exit the loop when the file is at the end. You shouldn't check for end of file like you are in your loop. This would require the end of file character to be somewhere in your file. The value of `EOF` is actually specifically designed so it doesn't appear in your files.

Other things to look at are uncommenting your check that the file was opened successfully. If this check is failing then you shouldn't attempt to use any of the `fxxx` functions on the file pointer.

Answer (score 0):

you are not checking for array boundaries of "archivo"
that'd be for me the first thing to check